# Role of MBR in the booting process

Tags: boot, partitioning

I am new to stack overflow. So please correct me if my question seems irrelevant or stupid.

I read here in [Booting Process](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/) : The job of the primary boot loader is to find and load the secondary boot loader (stage 2). It does this by looking through the partition table for an active partition. When it finds an active partition, it scans the remaining partitions in the table to ensure that they're all inactive. When this is verified, the active partition's boot record is read from the device into RAM and executed.

The question is that I am having a Hard disk which has two Operating System images windows and ubuntu and hence both partitions in which they reside are active. Then why do we have only one active partition always? (I know that active partition is one of the primary partition but then why we are giving special reference to one primary partition? ) I am confused a bit. Please solve my query.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Every partition has a bit which specifies whether that bit is the active partition.  "Then why do we have only one active partition always?" - we don't, necessarily.  Most "fdisk" programs clear all other partition active bits (to zero) any time they set any partition active bit (to one).  Not all do that (OpenBSD's  fidsk doesn't), so it is possible to have multiple active partitions.  Such an occurrence is a violation of a common assumption, so behavior is probably technically undefined (but the usual behavior is to just act on the first partition with that active bit set).

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking "active" as meaning "existing".
Active in the sense of a partition table more or less really means "Boot from this one".
You should only ever have 1 marked as the boot partition, and the BIOS or MBR would usually only stop when the first one is found as it wouldn't make sense to HALT the entire system in the case of a superfluous boot partition.

In the case of computers with more than one "bootable partition", a boot manager (Windows has one built in, there's also LILO, GRUB, etc) is installed in the MBR which then prompts and redirects the boot process to the selected partitions based on user input or default timeout, regardless of this flag.

Comment: So, how does it decide which is the active partition? I have read that second stage bootloader in linux is GRUB in grub.cfg and boot.ini in Windows. When I installed ubuntu through wubi.exe the boot.ini is loaded (i.e. windows 2nd stage bootloader) but if I install it using ubuntu live-cd or bootable usb, grub is loaded as 2nd stage bootloader. How does it happens?

Comment: If there is no boot menu in the MBR (the MBR contains a small program/code) it will pick the first one marked for boot ("active"). and if this fails you will see an error generated by the MBR ("Check disk drive", "NTLDR Missing", "GRUB 0x293429873643").  Grub places code in the MBR that then loads the GRUB program from your /boot partition.  Installing different OSes tends to re-write the MBR in its favour.

Answer (score 1):

The original IBM/Microsoft boot loader works as described (searching for an active partition). This behavior isn't true of all boot loaders, though. In particular, boot loaders common in Linux, such as LILO and GRUB, work in other ways; they ignore the active flag and instead present a menu to the user, enabling the user to choose which OS to boot. DOS and Windows 9x/Me required that they boot from a partition with the active flag set, but I'm pretty sure that this is no longer true of more modern versions of Windows.

Furthermore, the entire process described in the article to which you linked is outdated. Modern computers (all Intel-based Macs, the vast majority of PCs that shipped with Windows 8, and many Windows 7 systems that shipped since mid-2011) boot using the [Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) or its updated version, the Unified EFI (UEFI).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uefi) An EFI boots in an entirely different way from a BIOS. (Confusingly, many people and even PC manufacturers apply the term "BIOS" to their EFIs, but this is misleading.) Under EFI, the MBR contains no code and there's no such thing as an "active" partition. Instead, as many boot loaders as you like are stored in the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) You choose the boot loader you want to use via a boot manager that's built into the firmware. Unfortunately, this built-in boot manager is often of poor quality, and it often requires hitting a function key at boot time to access it, so many dual-booters set a third-party boot manager (GRUB, rEFInd, gummiboot, etc.) as the default.

To be sure, plenty of computers still boot using the old BIOS methods -- they're mostly older PCs, but most modern EFIs include a BIOS compatibility mode and so can be configured to boot in the old way, with which many users are more familiar. Switching boot modes requires re-installing a boot loader, though, and sometimes switching the partition table in use, so it's often not done except when wiping a disk clean and re-installing everything.

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest me any link having nice stuff about this?

Comment: Up vote for the deep technical answer here.

Comment: @pg4421 you may find more information in his [website](http://www.rodsbooks.com/)

Answer (score 0):

the following might address the particular point where you are stuck, but i'm not expert on the way the boot process works generally.

One Hard Drive has only One active partition

So if you have two Hard drives then each could have an active partition

The BIOS picks what hard drive to boot off.

The active partition (of that hard drive) is then booted from.

You talk about images, that may be relevant when and if writing a partition or writing all partitions, but it's not relevant after you've done that writing. After you've done that writing, you have a hard drive with partitions. Just as you would have if you took a hard drive fresh with no partitions and created them and installed OSs on them. Image files and burnt images just aren't relevant.